# How to get button for which listener's method was invoked

Tags: java, android

When I have:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //getSource button here --->actionButton

            }
        }
button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

How to get button which was clicked inside `onClick` method?

Comment: Extending on what everyone said, if your class implements the OnClickListener interface, you can have a single onClick method within your activity that uses switch(v.getId()){ case R.id."id_name": .... for multiple buttons

Answer (score 2):

See the `v` parameter on the [`onClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick%28android.view.View%29) method which represents the view that was clicked.

Then you can use [`v.getId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29) to see which view has been clicked.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
        //button1 clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `id`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   //getSource button here --->actionButton
   if (v.getId() == R.id.someId)
      // do some stuff
}
```

In this case, `v` is the `Button` clicked so you can get the `id` of that `View` (`Button`) and compare it using `==` or put it in a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id of pressed `Button` using `getId()` method.

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
            Toast.makeText(this, button.getText().toString()+" button is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In xml file use `android:onClick="onClick"` and `view.getId()` will get the id of button in which it was clicked and use switch case statement to do related jobs for each button. The code will look like this:

`public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            //Do something for this button
            break;
        case R.id.buttton2:
            //DO something for this button
            break;
}`